# Inverse row selection for concatenated pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For the development of a regression multiple experiments are recorded. All experiments are concatenated into a single dataframe. For the training I'd like to use every n'th sample and visualize the performance on the remaining data.

The following code works fine for a single experiment, but fails with the concatenated data due to re-occurring indexes.

```py
df = pd.read_pickle(concatenated_experiments.pkl)
train = df.iloc[::10, :]
test = df.loc[~df.index.isin(train.index)]
```

Is there a clever way to achieve this with a concatenated dataframe? I already trained some models using `df.iloc[::10, :]` and would prefer not needing to redo them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use modulo with `10` and compare by `0` for boolean mask and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), `~` is for invert mask:

```
df = pd.read_pickle(concatenated_experiments.pkl)

#if default RangeIndex
#mask = df.index % 10 == 0

#general solution
mask = np.arange(len(df)) % 10 == 0
train = df[~mask]
test = df[mask]
```

Comment: My comment was referring to your initial answer. The proposed solution with the mask works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @Fabitosh - Super, glad can help!